# Почему слетают выбранные значения в самописном мультиселекте в админке при обновлении страницы?

Tags: django, django-admin

Я написал форму мультиселекта для админки. Выбранные данные сохраняются в бд, но по какой-то причине они не отображаются, как выбранные.

Когда я снова пытаюсь сохранить объект, получаю ошибку, что данные не выбраны. Такое ощущение, что при обновлении страницы селекты просто слетают.

Использую `django-jet`

В чем может быть проблема?

Поле *регистрация*
[image]

```
class ConditionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """docstring for ConditionAdminForm."""
    REGISTRATION_CHOICES= (
        ('Any', _('Any')),
        ('Constant', _('Constant')),
        ('Temporary', _('Temporary')),
    )
​
    registration = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = REGISTRATION_CHOICES, label=_("registration form"))
​
    def clean_registration(self):
        registration = self.cleaned_data['registration']
        if not registration:
            raise forms.ValidationError("...")
​
        registration = ', '.join(registration)
        return registration
​
    class Meta:
        model = Condition
        fields = '__all__'
​
​
class ConditionInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Condition
    form = ConditionAdminForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ConditionAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    obj = kwargs.get('instance')
    if obj:
        initial = [i for i in obj.registration.split(', ')]
        self.initial['registration'] = initial
```